# How can I add multiple private IP addresses for a single machine?

Tags: windows, ip, cloud, godaddy

I have one Windows cloud server on [Go Daddy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Go_Daddy). They gave me 3 public IP addresses and one private IP address per machine. And I know for more public IP addresses I have to call Go Daddy.

How can I add more private IP addresses to a single machine ([Windows Server 2008](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Server_2008)).

Comment: Can you explain why you want to do this? How do you use the private addresses - does Go Daddy give you a vpn to your private network?

Comment: @Julian in Go Daddy cloud servers we cant use public ip addresses directly like vps and other. We must forward public ips to private ip to use in IIS. for that godaddy will give you a private ip per machine. if you have multiple machines then you can get multiple private ips and you can connect through VPN which provided with every network. Hope you understand..

Comment: Just looked at http://www.godaddy.com/hosting/cloud-computing.aspx - so they NAT your three public addresses to your one private one. That should be fine - for a web server you can use virtual hosts to serve different sites to different IP addresses. I'm still not getting the use case that means you need multiple private addresses.

Comment: @Julian in IIS i can use that one private ip only. so i cant run multiple applications without host headers using ip. so you are going to ask me - why i need to do that?. pls refer this http://serverfault.com/questions/387693/exact-alternate-for-port-80/

Comment: But the host headers will have the public, not the private IPs in them, and you can give them different dns names. So host headers should be fine shouldn't it?

Answer (score 5):

One NIC supports more than one IP. To add them simplyClick on Start button

1. Open Control Panel
2. Click on Network and Sharing Center
3. Click on Manage Network Connections
4. Right Click on the active network icon  and select Properties
5. Select Internet Protocol Version (TCP/IP). There may be more then
   version. (Use 4 unless you are using IPv6)
6. Now click on Properties button
7. Click on Advanced tab
8. Now you need to add in an IP address section Enter IP details such
   as IP address, Subnetmask etc
9. Save the changes and go back to Windows server desktop

[image]

[Source](http://www.cosmocentral.com/2010/01/how-to-add-an-additional-ip-address-in-windows-server-2003-and-2008/)

Answer (score 4):

You probably can't. Lucas gave the technical details of how to do it in the operating system, but since you're on a cloud service network, that probably won't work out well for you. Some cloud providers allow private networks in the sense of fully segmented VLANs that you can control, but that's usually an exceptional offering.

If they've done things right, the VM networking / switch fabric won't talk to anything on your machine that doesn't match the defined MAC and IP addresses that are expected.

If they've done it wrong, you'll conflict with another system and then lots of people will make grumpy faces.

Comment: When *don't* we make grumpy faces?

Answer (score 2):

To use your example on: [Alternative to Port 80 for http](https://serverfault.com/questions/387693/alternative-to-port-80-for-http)

Configure *.example.com to IP 192.108.0.0 port 80, portforward from publicip1 port 80 to port 80 on your server, point dns for example.com to publicip1

Configure *.domain2.com to 192.108.0.0 port 81, portforward from publicip2 port80 to port 81 on your server, point dns for domain2.com to publicip2

Repeat increasing the the local port for each website that you want.

Note: If you ask for additional IP's using this as your justification you will be denied, as this is not a valid reason for additional IP's.

Your private network in Go Daddy Cloud Server Console is private to you, you can add as many private IP's that you want to your servers.  Only those in your subnet will be able to get out to the internet (NAT'd behind the primary ip).  However, we currently only support configuring port forwarding rules to the internal IPaddress that was assigned to the machine.  IE you can add whatever IP that you want, but currently we will only use the original private IP address to assign rules.

Comment: Also, we have an in house forum for questions about Cloud Servers that you may wish to use.
http://support.godaddy.com/groups/virtual-datacenter/forum/