# Alternative to Port 80 for http

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis, http, port

In Windows Server 2008 we can host multiple websites under a single IP by relying on Host headers. My problem is I have only one IP address and I want to dedicate it to a single application like below:

> Host : *  (for any host header. to provide *.example.com)
>   IP : 192.108.0.0
>   Port : 80

Now I want to do this with another application, too, like this:

> Host : *  (for any host header. to provide ***.domain2.com**)
>   IP : 192.108.0.0
>   Port : 80

I can't use the same IP twice because it will create a conflict. So I thought I would use an alternative to port 80 and redo the second application like below:

> Host : *  (for any host header. to provide *.domain2.com)
>   IP : 192.108.0.0
>   Port : 234

Is this possible? Can I then connect to domain2.com without specifying the port in the URL?

Need this => domain2.com
Not this => domain2.com:234

I am using IIS.

Comment: What web server are you using?

Comment: Windows Server 2008 with IIS 7

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't run on a different port than port 80 without specifying the port in the URL.

But why can't you just set your web server to provide the first site when the Host: header matches "*.example.com" and the second site when it matches "*.domain2.com"?  (Someone might even be able to tell you how to do that if you tell us what web server you're using.)

Comment: @wafaulk yes we can use just "example.com". but my problem is i want host header like *.example.com & *.domain2.com. if i leave host header field as blank then any host header which one pointing to this ip will work automatically. So i can easily get unlimited subdomains without manual creation by single DNS A record. for example "anyhostheader.blogspot.com"

Comment: I understand, but, depending on your web server, you might be able to use wildcards exactly like in your comment, which would make more sense.

Comment: @wafualk am unable to create multiple wildcard domains with a single ip

Comment: in iis we can't use any host header with a symbol like * in website bindings

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Apache you can use name based virtual hosts.  It provides a solution to this exact situation whereby it will answer for any domain you wish on the same IP address.

Comment: it may be. but am using windows server 2008 :(

Comment: @Svinn - Apache does run under Windows. I think you mean to indicate you're using IIS

Comment: yes using IIS 7 @wfaulk

Comment: @Svinn IIS does name based virtual hosts too

Comment: bcoz of this http://dirk.net/2008/05/28/wildcard-host-header-binding-and-subdomains-with-iis7/ i cant use name based virtual hosts for wildcards